# How to treat the TextView in Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Although I would like to preserve the contents in a `TextView`, and the portion of reading not to iOS but to Mac O SX, I do not go well.

What should be done with the expression:

```
NSString *string = myTextView.text;
```

...used when treating the `TextView` of the instance name of `myTextView` in Mac OS X?

Since I received indication as explanation was lacking, I add a sentence. I would like to make this code into MacOSX. I treat NSTextView.

```
- (void)saveFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"memo.txt"];
    NSString *string =myTextView.text;
    [string writeToFile:path
             atomically:YES 
               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                  error:NULL];    
}
- (void)loadFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"memo.txt"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                        error:NULL];
        myTextView.text = string;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question. Can you please explain more about what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

I think I might actually know what your talking about.

I'm assuming you have an OSX app with an `NSTextField` named `myTextView`. You are trying do do the Mac equivalent of `myTextView.text`. If so you want to do:

```
NSString *string = myTextView.stringValue;
```

Response to question edit:

As one might guess to set the value of the textfield you would do the inverse:

```
myTextView.stringValue = string;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I did not expect that a reply came early this much. 
Although the expected thing was differed from for a while, since it was one of the things to know, it is very helpful.

Comment: I was able to want to do, when writing in with myTextView.string. 
Thank you for answering variously.